# RNGCryptoServiceProvider random string. always returns a string that ends with '='

Tags: c#, random, rngcryptoserviceprovider

```
static public string GetRandomSalt(int saltLength)
    {
        byte[] saltByte = new byte[saltLength];

        using (var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {

            random.GetBytes(saltByte);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(saltByte);
    }
```

so if the salt length is 8, it will returns some random string but ends with '=', how do I avoid it? looked at other stack overflow solution, but still cannot fix it

Comment: You *don't* fix it. You've created a base-64 encoded string, presumably to pass to something/someone else who will base-64 decode it (if not, why are you doing that conversion at all?). When they decode it, they *expect* the `=` to be there.

Answer (score 1):

It's just Base64 padding you can't avoid, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding). See also [Base64 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-5).

I recommend using salt as byte array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to the use of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, but rather that you are converting the result to base-64.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The valueless character "=" is used for trailing padding.

So, I can think of three options:

1. Stop using base-64 formatting (possibly return the bytes themselves).
2. Accept the fact that base-64 uses `=` for padding.
3. Pass a length that doesn't require padding, like 9.

Example for point 3:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
```

produces

```
AQIDBAUGBwgJ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetUniqueKey(int maxSize)
{
    char[] chars = new char[62];
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".ToCharArray();
    byte[] data = new byte[1];
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
        data = new byte[maxSize];
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
    foreach (byte b in data)
    {
        result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```